# Passing arguments to test script when running unit tests with hardhat

Tags: unit-testing, npm, ethereum, npx, hardhat

I have a suite of unit tests which test some solidity smart contracts. These all work fine, however the location of the solidity smart contract file is hard coded into the javascript test files.

I would like to pass the location of this file as an argument to my test script, however i cannot find a way to do this with hardhat.

I currently run my tests like this:

> npx hardhat test "./scripts/erc20tests.js"

I would like to be able to run it like:

> npx hardhat test "./scripts/erc20tests.js" "../../erc20.sol"

but this doesnt work. Its not accepted as valid my hardhat.  Any suggestions?

My other option would be to set this value as an environmental variable, but i dont like this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native NodeJS `process.argv` property ([docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv)) to read the commandline arguments.

Then you can load the `.sol` file dynamically.

```
const contract = await ethers.deployContract(process.argv[4] || defaultContract);
```

---

*Note: It's generally recommended to put the test files into the `test` folder. The `scripts` folder is used for scripts that are executed by the `npx hardhat run` command. ([docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/project-setup#sample-hardhat-project))*

Comment: Yes but how do i run the tests and pass the arguments to the test script?

Comment: @CathalMF When you run this test command: `npx hardhat test "./scripts/erc20tests.js" "../../erc20.sol"`, the value of `process.argv[4]` is `../../erc20.sol`. So that's how you effectively pass the arguments to the test script... If you want to pass the values from console to the smart contract, you can pass them in a constructor argument or a setter function.